# how to avoid the error due to missing element from an XML file in Flash Action Script

Tags: xml, apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a code which is written for read the xml data. and the xml file contains the optional values, so some time the elements are present there some times not. In this case how can i set a default value for that in action script 3.0.

When i tried to trace the value that area is skipping. So is there any other method to trace-out is that element is present or not something like that??

**Edit:**

```
private function xmlListener(evt:Event) {
    xmlValue = new XML(evt.target.data);
    _videoURL = xmlValue.videoUrl;
    _setWidth = xmlValue.setWidth;
    _setHeight = xmlValue.setHeight;
}
```

Suppose the set '**setHeight**' element is not present in the XML then what would be the value of **_setHeight** ??

**Edit 2:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
    <videoUrl>videos.flv</videoUrl>
    <setWidth>500</setWidth>
</settings>
```

Comment: How are you processing the XML? E4X?

Comment: How about an example of the XML

Comment: Thanks, realized I didn't really need it after I asked :-)  oh well better too much than too little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_setHeight = (xmlValue.setHeight.length() >0)?xmlValue.setHeight:0;
```

Answer (score 0):

When trying to access XML nodes that may not exist you should try using the `child()`, `attribute()` and `element()` functions from the `XML` class. Either of these returns an `XMLList` and if the specified node doesn't exist the `XMLList` is simply empty (with a `length` of 0) instead of the Flash Player immediately barfing up an `Error`.

From [Flex Livedocs - Traversing XML structures](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=13_Working_with_XML_08.html) :

> If you try to filter on attributes or elements that may not exist, Flash®
>   Player and Adobe® AIR™ will throw an
>   exception. For example, the final line
>   of the following code generates an
>   error, because there is no id
>   attribute in the second p element:
>
> ```
> var doc:XML = 
>             <body>
>                 <p id='123'>Hello, <b>Bob</b>.</p>
>                 <p>Hello.</p>
>             </body>;
> trace(doc.p.(@id == '123'));
> ```
>
> Similarly, the final line of following code generates an error
>   because there is no b property of the
>   second p element:
>
> ```
> var doc:XML = 
>             <body>
>                 <p id='123'>Hello, <b>Bob</b>.</p>
>                 <p>Hello.</p>
>             </body>;
> trace(doc.p.(b == 'Bob'));
> ```
>
> To avoid these errors, you can identify the properties that have the
>   matching attributes or elements by
>   using the attribute() and elements()
>   methods, as in the following code:
>
> ```
> var doc:XML = 
>             <body>
>                 <p id='123'>Hello, <b>Bob</b>.</p>
>                 <p>Hello.</p>
>             </body>;
> trace(doc.p.(attribute('id') == '123'));
> trace(doc.p.(elements('b') == 'Bob'));
> ```
>
> You can also use the hasOwnProperty() method, as in the
>   following code:
>
> ```
> var doc:XML = 
>             <body>
>                 <p id='123'>Hello, <b>Bob</b>.</p>
>                 <p>Hello.</p>
>             </body>;
> trace(doc.p.(hasOwnProperty('@id') && @id == '123'));
> trace(doc.p.(hasOwnProperty('b') && b == 'Bob'));
> ```

Answer (score -1):

```
if(xmlElement != null){

// do stuff here if it has a set value

}else{
// if it is empty then give it a value like this:

xmlElement = defultvalue;
}
```

Comment: I don't think the the null thing works, I think you need to check for undefined. or you can do what I do in my answer

Comment: the undefined and null are not working, you may please check by writting your own codes, I failed if conditions that is why am here :(